# many-to-many self-referencing association in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to do this:

Person <--Many-to-many---> Person

I want to have a relation where one person can have many (more than one) parents and one parent can have many childs (more then one)

My hibernate mapping

```
@Entity
class Person{

    @Id
    @Column
    long id;

    @Column
    String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Person_Parent", 
      joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name = "parent_ID") },
      inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "child_ID")})
    private Set<Person> parent = new HashSet<Person>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Person_Parent", 
      joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name = "child_ID") },
      inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "parent_ID")})
    private Set<Person> child = new HashSet<Person>();
}
```

Is this mapping correct? how to make this relation bidirectional. so that if I add a Parent. that Parent's child collection should be updated.

Comment: did you try running it? did it work? any exceptions? we don't do code review here (not trying to be rude), please explain what issue you are facing so that we can help.

Comment: Normally you map the inverse side with a `mappedBy` attribute in the `@ManyToMany` annotation as opposed to specifying the mapping details again. You may also want to name the fields `parents` and `children` just to make the code clearer.

Comment: @AnanthaSharma yes i did, i get infinite recursion when adding parent/child. when that person has another parent. also in bidirectional mapping, when i add a parent that parent's child collection should get cascaded right? but nope its not. I tried with mappedBy. but this issues did not get solved.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing for certain what your issue is, I believe you might be having problems because you have not set a "mappedBy" value for "owning" side of the relationship. Example:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Person> parent = new HashSet<Person>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="parent")
private Set<Person> child = new HashSet<Person>();
```

(I've removed the `@JoinTable` for brevity's sake.) Furthermore, you may be interested in a better way of suppressing your JSON serialization by using the following annotations as opposed to `@JsonIgnore`:

```
@JsonBackReference
private Set<Person> parent = new HashSet<Person>();

@JsonManagedReference
private Set<Person> child = new HashSet<Person>();
```